# How can I write a LINQ to SQL query to update tags?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, tagging

I have an image site where users can tag photos much like you can tag a question on Stackoverflow.

I have the following tables:

```
Images [ID, URL, etc]   
Tags  [ID, TagName]    
ImageTag  [TagID, ImageID]
```

I want to write a method with the signature:

```
public void UpdateImageTags(int imageId, IEnumerable<string> currentTags)
```

This method will do the following:

- Create any new Tags in currentTags that don't already exist in the Tags table.
- Get the old ImageTag's for an image.

  - Delete any ImageTag's that no longer exist in the currentTags
  - Add any ImageTag's that are new between the currentTags and oldTags.

Here is my attempt at that method:

```
public void UpdateImageTags(int imageId, IEnumerable<string> currentTags)
{
    using (var db = new ImagesDataContext())
    {
        var oldTags = db.ImageTags.Where(it => it.ImageId == imageId).Select(it => it.Tag.TagName);
        var added = currentTags.Except(oldTags);
        var removed = oldTags.Except(currentTags);

        // Add any new tags that need created
        foreach (var tag in added)
        {
            if (!db.Tags.Any(t => t.TagName == tag))
            {
                db.Tags.InsertOnSubmit(new Tag { TagName = tag });
            }
        }               
        db.SubmitChanges();

        // Delete any ImageTags that need deleted.
        var deletedImageTags = db.ImageTags.Where(it => removed.Contains(it.Tag.TagName));
        db.ImageTags.DeleteAllOnSubmit(deletedImageTags);

        // Add any ImageTags that need added.
        var addedImageTags = db.Tags.Where(t => added.Contains(t.TagName)).Select(t => new ImageTag { ImageId = imageId, TagId = t.TagId });
        db.ImageTags.InsertAllOnSubmit(addedImageTags);
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

However, this fails on the line:

```
db.ImageTags.DeleteAllOnSubmit(deletedImageTags);
```

With the error:

> Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query
>   operators except the Contains operator.

Is there an easier way I can handle the operation of adding new tags, deleting old ImageTags, adding new ImageTags in LINQ to SQL?

Comment: How many tags exist in te database? This would be a critical factor here between "read all the tags from the DB and compare" vs "query per item"

Comment: @Marc Gravell, There will likely be thousands of tags. Maybe more than 10k, less than 50k?  Total guess.  It is still in development and we have almost a thousand already.

Comment: Can it not be done in TSQL at the server then?

Comment: @Mac Gravell, Yea, it could.  Is there some limitation with linq to sql that would prohibit it from doing this efficiently?

Comment: @Viktor Is there a limit? The overhead of hydrating all of those objects, making the change, and pushing them back is significantly higher than issuing a single Update statement at the database level without having to pass all of that data across the network. Put it in a stored proc and call the proc using LINQ if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this would be easiest

```
public void UpdateImageTags(int imageId, IEnumerable<string> currentTags) 
{ 
    using (var db = new ImagesDataContext()) 
    { 
        var image = db.Images.Where(it => it.ImageId == imageId).First()
        image.Tags.Clear();
        foreach(string s in currentTags)
        {
            image.Tags.Add(new Tag() { TagName = s});
        } 
        db.SubmitChanges();  
    }
 }
```

This might have to be modified slightly for LinqtoSQL. EF is what i have been using most recently. Also this is dependent on Lazy loading being enabled. If it is not, you will have to force the include of the image tags.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a helper method to deal with many-to-many relationships:

```
public static void UpdateReferences<FK, FKV>(
    this EntitySet<FK> refs,
    Expression<Func<FK, FKV>> fkexpr,
    IEnumerable<FKV> values)
  where FK : class
  where FKV : class
{
  Func<FK, FKV> fkvalue = fkexpr.Compile();
  var fkmaker = MakeMaker(fkexpr);
  var fkdelete = MakeDeleter(fkexpr);

  var fks = refs.Select(fkvalue).ToList();
  var added = values.Except(fks);
  var removed = fks.Except(values);

  foreach (var add in added)
  {
    refs.Add(fkmaker(add));
  }

  foreach (var r in removed)
  {
    var res = refs.Single(x => fkvalue(x) == r);
    refs.Remove(res);
    fkdelete(res);
  }
}

static Func<FKV, FK> MakeMaker<FKV, FK>(Expression<Func<FK, FKV>> fkexpr)
{
  var me = fkexpr.Body as MemberExpression;

  var par = Expression.Parameter(typeof(FKV), "fkv");
  var maker = Expression.Lambda(
      Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(typeof(FK)),
        Expression.Bind(me.Member, par)), par);

  var cmaker = maker.Compile() as Func<FKV, FK>;
  return cmaker;
}

static Action<FK> MakeDeleter<FK, FKV>(Expression<Func<FK, FKV>> fkexpr)
{
  var me = fkexpr.Body as MemberExpression;
  var pi = me.Member as PropertyInfo;

  var assoc = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(pi, typeof(AssociationAttribute))
    as AssociationAttribute;

  if (assoc == null || !assoc.DeleteOnNull)
  {
    throw new ArgumentException("DeleteOnNull must be set to true");
  }

  var par = Expression.Parameter(typeof(FK), "fk");
  var maker = Expression.Lambda(
      Expression.Call(par, pi.GetSetMethod(),
        Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(null), typeof(FKV))), par);

  var cmaker = maker.Compile() as Action<FK>;
  return cmaker;
}
```

Usage:

```
IEnumerable<Tag> values = ...;
Image e = ...;
e.ImageTags.UpdateReferences(x => x.Tag, tags);
```